# Replacing Inner Join with a SubQuery in SQL

Tags: mysql

I came across an example of how a SQL statement with INNER JOIN can be replaced by one with a subquery in the SELECT clause.

There are 2 tables--Countries (code, name, continent, region, surface_area) and Cities (name, country_code, city_proper_pop, metroarea_pop).

SQL statement with INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT countries.name AS country, COUNT(*) AS cities_num
FROM cities
    INNER JOIN countries
    ON countries.code = cities.country_code
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY cities_num DESC, country
LIMIT 9;
```

This returns the table:
[image]

With a Subquery in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT countries.name AS country,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM cities
   WHERE countries.code = cities.country_code) AS cities_num
FROM countries
ORDER BY cities_num DESC, country
LIMIT 9;
```

which shows the same result.

Why can the nested SQL query contain the condition `countries.code = cities.country_code` in the WHERE clause without performing a join? Because the nested query only draws its result from `cities`; it does not specify `countries`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Debug questions require a [mre]. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called correlated sub query.

For every row of outer query, it will run the inner query, in programming terms something like loop inside a loop.

More info..

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-correlated-subqueries/